# TextBox Auto Expandable in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, textbox, expandable

I have a `TextBox` like this;

```
<asp:TextBox id="TextBox1" TextMode="SingleLine" runat="server" />
```

Is there any way making`Auto Expandable` without `Javascript` or any other technology?

Can i do that just with `ASP.NET` ? (Some properties maybe)

OR what is the easiest way?

Comment: "Auto Expandable" is auto re-size widht of 'TextBox'. When i write 5 letters 'TextBox.Widht' should be 50 px, for 10 letters should be 100px for example..!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use ASP.NET AJAX ResizableControl Extender if you plan on using ajax control toolkit.(Which internally uses javascript I think),  I'm not aware of any other non-javascript way.

Comment: But this isn't automaticly right? Yes it can provide re-size properties but users must changes size of control. Is there any automaticly way?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. basically, every action in client-side is handled by javascript. That's the only language browsers understand.

Answer (score 1):

You only can make it without javascript if you already know the content and you don't want the width to change dynamically while the user types. Something like `Width="<%=(SourceString.Length * 10)%>"`

Comment: If you already know the content whatz the purpose of letting the user type it (unless you are doing some type test)

Comment: That's a limitation for not using javascript ;)

Comment: @bortao Do you know the right syntax for that? **Width="<%=(SourceString.Length * 10)%>"** doesn't work.

Comment: Just put TextBox1.Width = SourceString.Length * 10 on your Page_Load

Comment: @bortao Is needed namespace ? Not found SourceString ??

Comment: SourceString would be the text you would display in the textbox. as i said, this only works if you already have the text before loading the page.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the dynamic server tag for setting the Width.

```
Width='<%# (Eval("DataSourceField").ToString().Length * 8)%>'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
protected void TextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int i = TextBox1.Text.Length;
        int rowsize = (i / 10)+2;
        TextBox1.Rows = rowsize;
        TextBox1.Focus();
    }
```

Try This...........